# Performance Issue in Laravel comparing with Lumen and Layout Extend issue

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, lumen

My code has right now two things. 1. API Controllers 2. Web Controller.

Using JQuery, I send request to API controller.

Yesterday I was thinking that I should move to Angular Js because if I am not writing any code in Web Controller as everything is in API controller. Then  accessing data through JQuery so why Laravel Blade?

Then I thought why Laravel? **[Why not Lumen for API](https://lumen.laravel.com/)**? Because Laravel is heavy framework comparing with Lumen and strips down the bootstrapping process to a minimum and Angular Js for Fetching the info and display it.

Unfortunately, I am still in problem. In Laravel Blade, we could use Layout and finally we could extend the layouts. In this way , we don't need to rewrite the complete Html everytime in new blade. But Will, Angular Js support Layout extend feature if I go for Lumen and Angular Js?

Comment: Well, I think you're misunderstanding angularjs Sir. In angularjs you don't have the necessity of extend a layout like we do in many php template engines which is very usefull by the way. In angularjs, your layout would be a statefull part of your interface, you don't have to reuse it because you don't need to reload a layout anymore. However, if your are talking about reusing an existing template on many widgets and stuff, yes, it is a possibility (also is highly probable). Also, if you could describe a scenario I will be able to give you a more elaborated answer about this.

Comment: In Angular Js, I was thinking about a layout where I could write these footer , header, side navigation and then extend it in different pages like Role Management, User Management, Permissions Management etc. I searched on google about how could I extend the layout in Angular Js, but could not find it.

Comment: You can do something like reuse layout parts, but as I said, it doesn't works like that, on angularjs everything happens on client side, therefore it has some differences with he html built on server side.

Comment: Should I go for Lumen and Angular Js combination?

Comment: Umm, I don't want to say that you should exactly do this, there is many consideration for doing such thing, I think the great beneffit of usign a framework like angularjs is for maintainability. However, by doing this you're adding a new complexity to your project that may require a bunch of rewriting code and migrations (or maybe not) and new knowlege requirement. Dispite the fact that it creates more work, in a long term it is much more viable to maintain. Regardles, it's much more productive (cool) writing your front end in such technology also it brings many gains to UX as well.

Comment: Disclaimer, I really recomend doing so, and also, consider doing a research among frameqorks and library like angularjs for you to see more about the single page apps (SPA) world. You can try Angular2, ReactJS+Redux, Emberjs, Aurelia, VuJs, etc. Both are really nice and easy to use and you may find one which fits your scenario properly. And in the end, if you don't find any of these intersting you can use the old and awesome AngularJs. CHeers :{D

Comment: Lumen's blade templating works like Laravel's. Lumen isn't any less heavy than Laravel is, it appears faster because it lacks features - and the ones it lacks are the ones that are really appealing. Use whatever you're most comfortable with, not what someone tells you to use. Do your own testing and research, good starting point is to check out these tools that @LenilsondeCastro mentioned and then pick the one you liked the most.